estimatr::lm_robust() estimating different coefficients from lm()
After running a panel model (5475 units, 13 years) with stats::lm(), I've been trying to estimate heteroskedasticity robust standard errors with estimatr::lm_robust(). It turns out that some coefficients estimated are (very) different in each function - which shouldn't happen (only se, t.test and p-values should change).
# df <- load(url("https://github.com/victorrssx/victorrssx/blob/main/df.RData?raw=true"))
df <- readRDS(url("https://github.com/victorrssx/victorrssx/raw/main/df.RDS")) %>% 
      dplyr::mutate(ano = as.factor(ano))


lm_mod <- stats::lm(tx_hom_tot ~ pos2018 + res_ou:pos2018 + ti:pos2018 + res_ou:ti:pos2018 + ano, data = df)
summary(lm_mod)

    Coefficients: (1 not defined because of singularities)
                      Estimate Std. Error t value             Pr(>|t|)    
    (Intercept)         26.827      0.382   70.25 < 0.0000000000000002 ***
    pos2018              2.927      0.538    5.44     0.00000005226909 ***
    ano2011              0.220      0.540    0.41              0.68385    
    ano2012              1.182      0.536    2.20              0.02754 *  
    ano2013              0.892      0.537    1.66              0.09640 .  
    ano2014              1.960      0.534    3.67              0.00025 ***
    ano2015              2.985      0.533    5.60     0.00000002131005 ***
    ano2016              5.556      0.530   10.48 < 0.0000000000000002 ***
    ano2017              6.835      0.528   12.95 < 0.0000000000000002 ***
    ano2018              4.841      0.531    9.12 < 0.0000000000000002 ***
    ano2019             -1.633      0.520   -3.14              0.00169 ** 
    ano2020              0.280      0.518    0.54              0.58944    
    ano2021             -0.272      0.517   -0.53              0.59925    
    ano2022                 NA         NA      NA                   NA    
    pos2018:res_ou       0.862      0.643    1.34              0.18005    
    pos2018:ti           2.874      0.629    4.57     0.00000498294524 ***
    pos2018:res_ou:ti    9.824      1.365    7.20     0.00000000000063 ***
            
lm_mod <- estimatr::lm_robust(tx_hom_tot ~ pos2018 + res_ou:pos2018 + ti:pos2018 + res_ou:ti:pos2018 + ano, data = df, se_type = "HC1")
summary(lm_mod)

Standard error type:  HC1 

Coefficients:
                            Estimate             Std. Error     t value  Pr(>|t|)
(Intercept)                   26.930              10407.875  0.00258749 0.9979355
pos2018            2842202543499.796 324275566161917504.000  0.00000876 0.9999930
ano2011                        0.222                196.496  0.00112810 0.9990999
ano2012                        1.179                330.843  0.00356436 0.9971561
ano2013                        0.890                397.685  0.00223694 0.9982152
ano2014                        1.957                125.512  0.01558929 0.9875621
ano2015                        2.982                396.852  0.00751471 0.9940042
ano2016                        5.553                470.073  0.01181333 0.9905746
ano2017                        6.832                355.406  0.01922433 0.9846622
ano2018                        4.838                355.006  0.01362761 0.9891271
ano2019           -2842202543498.518 264769891052461504.000 -0.00001073 0.9999914
ano2020           -2842202543497.091 374441170828414656.000 -0.00000759 0.9999939
ano2021           -2842202543497.189 324275566161908160.000 -0.00000876 0.9999930
ano2022           -2842202543496.979 324275566161925760.000 -0.00000876 0.9999930
pos2018:res_ou                 0.863                  5.743  0.15017708 0.8806255
pos2018:ti                     2.874                  0.677  4.24755884 0.0000216
pos2018:res_ou:ti              9.852               2739.434  0.00359654 0.9971304

Specifically, the problem happens sharply on pos2018, ano2019, ano2020, ano2021 which are all dummies. The first is set to 1 for years after 2018 and 0 otherwise; the remainder are year-specific dummies. Even setting fixed_effects = ~ ano produce strange results.
lm_mod <- estimatr::lm_robust(tx_hom_tot ~ pos2018 + res_ou:pos2018 + ti:pos2018 + res_ou:ti:pos2018, data = df, se_type = "HC1", fixed_effects = ~ ano)
summary(lm_mod) 

Standard error type:  HC1 

Coefficients: (1 not defined because the design matrix is rank deficient)
                  Estimate Std. Error t value   Pr(>|t|) CI Lower CI Upper    DF
pos2018                 NA         NA      NA         NA       NA       NA    NA
pos2018:res_ou       0.862      0.707    1.22 0.22251985   -0.523     2.25 50693
pos2018:ti           2.874      0.640    4.49 0.00000709    1.620     4.13 50693
pos2018:res_ou:ti    9.824      2.252    4.36 0.00001292    5.409    14.24 50693

When using lmtest::coeftest(lm_mod, vcov. = plm::vcovHC(lm_mod, type = "HC1")) it seems to produce correct results. So why is this happening with lm_robust? Could it be due to the interpretation of the NAs in the data by the function?

Both models have a rank-deficient design matrix. I expect that is the reason. Apparently, lm_robust can't handle that appropriately. (Btw., I'm not loading an RData file from an untrusted source. Share data in a more secure way.)

Hi @Roland! I shared it as .RData file because I was seeking to reproduce the dataframe structure exactly and the data is large  enough to run dput(). I tried storing it as a .csv first but then identical() returned FALSE when comparing the loaded df with the imported one - even making the columns the same type. Do you have any suggestions for how to share this in an acceptable way?

saveRDS is more secure because it serializes only one object and doesn't (potentially) save a bunch of environments and stuff.

@Roland done: post edited!

Source code looks like it is supposed to handle rank-deficient cases? https://github.com/DeclareDesign/estimatr/blob/main/src/lm_robust_helper.cpp#L158-L203

You might file an issue at the authors' github. This does not prevent you from calculating HC1 errors using the classic method in the meantime:
> lmtest::coeftest(lm_mod, vcov.=sandwich::vcovHC(lm_mod, type='HC1'))

t test of coefficients:

                  Estimate Std. Error t value  Pr(>|t|)    
(Intercept)       26.82729    0.33009 81.2731 < 2.2e-16 ***
pos2018            2.92704    0.51619  5.6705 1.432e-08 ***
ano2011            0.21990    0.46329  0.4747  0.635035    
ano2012            1.18210    0.47655  2.4805  0.013122 *  
ano2013            0.89249    0.47448  1.8810  0.059979 .  
ano2014            1.95953    0.47255  4.1467 3.378e-05 ***
ano2015            2.98510    0.48176  6.1962 5.827e-10 ***
ano2016            5.55602    0.50851 10.9262 < 2.2e-16 ***
ano2017            6.83532    0.52874 12.9275 < 2.2e-16 ***
ano2018            4.84076    0.52573  9.2076 < 2.2e-16 ***
ano2019           -1.63344    0.53712 -3.0411  0.002358 ** 
ano2020            0.27967    0.55194  0.5067  0.612367    
ano2021           -0.27170    0.56632 -0.4798  0.631404    
pos2018:res_ou     0.86248    0.70703  1.2199  0.222520    
pos2018:ti         2.87381    0.63982  4.4916 7.085e-06 ***
pos2018:res_ou:ti  9.82393    2.25226  4.3618 1.292e-05 ***
---
Signif. codes:  0 ‘***’ 0.001 ‘**’ 0.01 ‘*’ 0.05 ‘.’ 0.1 ‘ ’ 1

Note that you should first run summary(lm_mod), otherwise you will miss important information that coeftest does not display.
